# Flask import error (python)

Tags: python, flask

Trying to import flask but I get the error:

```
ImportError: No module named Flask
```

after:

```
import Flask
```

I just installed it using terminal (Mac OS X):

```
JoeDangers-MacBookPro:~ joedanger$ $sudo easy_install Flask
Searching for Flask
Best match: Flask 0.10.1
Processing Flask-0.10.1-py2.7.egg
Flask 0.10.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
```

Any thoughts as to why this is not working?

Answer (score 3):

The module is called `flask`:

```
from flask import Flask
```

Comment: Then your `PYTHONPATH` is invalid or the package didn't install correctly. Make sure `easy_install` uses the same `PYTHONPATH` as your Python interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

## You can use virtual environment

> $ pip install virtualenv

Create virtualenv:

> $ virtualenv venv

- *venv is virtual environment name. Just name it what u want.

Activate virtual environment:

> $ source venv/bin/activate

Make sure your terminal like this:

> (venv) user@username:

Installing flask

> pip install flask

And you can import flask without error :)

To deactivate, just type:

> deactivate

Answer (score 0):

uninstall the package and then reinstall it again using pip " `pip install Flask` "  after that use this command to import the package:

```
from flask import Flask
```

edit:
are you using virtualenv ? if not then i recommend you to install it first 
use this command:

```
pip install python-virtualenv
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using mac terminal then check the python version which is linked to pip. Suppose for example if pip is linked to python version 2.7 use

```
➜  ~ python
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import flask

(or) 

➜  ~ python app.py
```

else if python version is 3.0 and above

```
➜  ~ python3
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import flask

(or)

➜  ~ python3 app.py
```

By using these commands you can check is flask is installed and if so for which python version